# Call must be used with function names starting with "un." in the uninstall section

Tags: function, nsis, uninstallation

```
...
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "XML.nsh"
  !insertmacro "UpdateXml"
...
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
UninstPage custom un.PageReinstall
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
...

Function un.PageReinstall
...
${UpdateXml} "http://127.0.0.1/123.xml" "/XML/A" $321 ; line 232 
...
FunctionEnd
```

NSIS log:

> !insertmacro: UpdateXmlCall Call must be used with function names
>   starting with "un." in the uninstall section. Usage: Call
>   function_name | [:label_name] Error in macro UpdateXmlCall on
>   macroline 5 Error in script "G:\Basic.nsi" on line 232 -- aborting
>   creation process

What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The functions that are used by the uninstaller must be prefixed with `un.`, and so do the macros.

Thus, if you are using a macro and want to be able to use it from both installer and uninstaller, you must insert it 2 times (one with and another without the `un.` prefix).

Adding or replacing the `!insertmacro "UpdateXml"` by `!insertmacro un.UpdateXml` at the begining of your script should fix the problem (provided that the `un.UpdateXml` macro is defined in the `xml.nsh`).

Comment: But it still makes it impossible to make good code since UpdateXml/un.UpdateXml can't call another macro. I get so frustrated!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [How to call an nsi function in uninstall section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597697/how-to-call-an-nsi-function-in-uninstall-section) shows how to avoid function duplication using macros:

```
!macro TestFunction UN
Function ${UN}TestFunction
   ;do stuff
FunctionEnd
!macroend
!insertmacro TestFunction "" 
!insertmacro TestFunction "un."
```

Usings:

```
Section "Install"
  Call TestFunction
EndSection

Section "Uninstall"
  Call un.TestFuction
SecionEnd
```